# How can I remove the session expiration for a user?

Tags: login, session

I want the session to keep on if I am not using the computer but it always changes to the login screen after few minutes

how can I remove that?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that go into your `System Settings` window and there choose there `Brightness & Lock`. within that dialog you find the setting to turn the `Lock` off.

[image]
[image]
[image]